# Xcode/iOS-Cannot edit content of Table View Cell...I'm using the storyboard editor

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, size, label

Hey guys this is my first question here on stackoverflow, but I've been browsing for quite some time.

I'm kind of new to iOS programming, but I feel like I'm getting the hang of it though.

I ran into this one issue today that just has me stuck though. I have a tableview with 8 prototype cells in it, and everything was working fine with them, then I realized I needed more cells. I add another cell, but then I found I couldn't resize the contents of the newly created cells. I don't think it's an issue with just my project because I just downloaded a tutorial that uses a tableview and I ran into the same issue.

Here are some pictures to show my issue: (I can't post images so here are the links)

Size inspector for one of the new cells:

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/2rwnhhu.png]

What happens when I click on the label in one of the original cells:

[image: http ://i40.tinypic . com / ay4vp3.png]

What happens when I click on the label in one of the new cells:

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/33b2y53.png]

Has anyone had this issue before?

What could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using more than 8 different kinds of cells?

Comment: What do you mean by different kinds of cells?? Sorry, I just had a tableview and clicked the up arrow to add more prototype cells...

Comment: At run time, do you want 8 different looking cells (different subviews, etc.), or do you want one kind of cell, just with different data displayed in each?

Comment: One kind of cell, just different data displayed in each (i.e. a label and an imageview in each cell)

Comment: Then I'm afraid you don't really have the hang of it just yet. A prototype is just that -- a prototype for creating as many identical cells as you need rows in your table. If you want one kind of cell, then you just need one prototype. You should read Apple's documentation on table views (it's linked at the top of the UITableView Class Reference).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't think that is my issue. I completed this tutorial here: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

and I believe it told me to increase the number of cells, now I'm just trying to add more but I'm running into this issue...

Comment: I think that's a bad tutorial -- it does make 8 different cells that each have different, but fixed content. If you want fixed content, then you should be using a static table view, not prototype cells. As far as your problem with sizing the subviews, I've never seen that before, so I'm guessing that you're doing something wrong in IB.

Comment: I don't believe I'm doing anything wrong though because I've downloaded their end result and tried to add new cells, but I get the same non-editable result :(

Comment: I just downloaded it and added new cells -- I didn't have any trouble resizing the label or image view.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm going to try re-installing xcode, must have been something I messed with before..

Answer (score 0):

![enter image description here][1]Got it, the cell you used is auto layout, do not check the auto layout in the xib or storyboard!

Interface Builder Document->Use Auto Layout   Don't check it!